# Scrollable tile views in iOS (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, tile

I am not the most experienced iOS developer and so far only had some simple designs I worked with, but now we plan to build views based on tiles, which I have no idea how to approach, yet. I tried searching for solutions, but haven’t really found something which could help. 
This is what we plan:

Row 1 (fix): Tile 1 (fix) | Tile 2 (fix) 
Row 2 (scrollable): Tile 3 | Tile 4 | Tile 5 | Tile 6 
*(unfortunately I am not allowed to post a picture)*

Two tiles per row should always be on the screen.

Each tile should contain its own layout and controls, in fact a MVC for each tile. The top two tiles should stay fixed on the screen, the second row contains four tiles that should be horizontally scrollable.

Could someone point me to the right MVC-architecture I should be using here? Are there maybe iOS controls which already support this.
Any hint on how to begin and how to design it is highly appreciated. Or a link to a tutorial.

I came across the UICollectionView, but I am not sure this is the right approach. I am planning to do that for iOS6, so I can also use the latest available controls/classes.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Nek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a view and a view controller. Add to this view a subview for the fixed tiles. Add to the rest of the screen a UICollectionView as a subview to the view. Assign data source and delegate to the UICollectionView and write the delegate and data source methods. You are done.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I will have a look into UICollectionView again. So far I only saw examples where they used it to show a set of pictures. If I get you right, you can place anything in such a UICollectionView?

Comment: An UICollectionView is something like a UITableView but better. You put into an UICollectionView cells and those cells are views. Therefore everything you can put into a view can be put into a cell of a UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIScrollView` class. In `UIScrollView` you can make it scrollable as you want.

For your requirement you can use `UIScrollView` as each row.

Comment: As he/she is developing of iOS6 a scroll view is here not recommended  because it does not reuse cells.